# PLSQL Package Variable Reference

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function that calls a package Call_Package. Within this package I have a procedure Validate_Procedure, and within this procedure I have a variable Entity_Flag.

The function calls my package as such:

```
BEGIN
Call_Package(<params>);
END
```

the 'Call_Package' contains my procedure Validate_Procedure as such:

```
Validate_Procedure(<paramA>, <paramB>)
```

within the procedure I do stuff, like normal:

```
Validate_Procedure(<params>) IS
BEGIN
 IF <paramA> THEN
  Entity_Flag = 1
 Else <paramB> THEN
  Entity_Flag = 2
 END IF
END
```

my question is, can I reference the procedural variable in my original function, like so:

```
BEGIN
Call_Package(<params>);
IF Call_Package.Validate_Procedure.Entity_Flag = 2 THEN
   {do stuff}
END IF
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot call a package.  A package is not an executable entity.  It is simply a collection of procedures, functions, package variables, etc.

If `Entity_Flag` is a local variable within the `Validate_Procedure` procedure, you cannot reference it from outside `Validate_Procedure`.  In the code you posted showing how the `Validate_Procedure` procedure is defined, however, you are not declaring `Entity_Flag`.  That may be an oversight or it may indicate that `Entity_Flag` is not a local variable at all.  Perhaps it is a package global variable.  If the variable is defined in the package specification, you could reference it outside the package, as `Call_Package.Entity_Flag`.  If the variable is defined in the package body, however, you can only reference it from inside another PL/SQL block defined in the package body.

Comment: Thanks, I'm extremely new to PLSQL, so I'm not sure of the terminology, or exactly what can be done. I appreciate the explanation. I was able to reach it because it is a package global variable, however, it's used in several procedures within the package and I am only able to use the initial instantiated variable of null.